Arithmetic operation of limits in extended real numbers
I'm studying measure theory and am confused about the Arithmetic operations of limits in extended real numbers.
For example, suppose we are in extended real numbers. $\lim a_n= a$, $\lim b_n= b$. To check $\lim b_n a_n= ba$, there are so many cases to consider and I almost got lost in dealing with them. I would like to know what the efficient way to prove it.
Moreover, I encounter other typical limit properties similar to those for real sequence. (Like the summation of limits is the limit of summations, monotonicity is preserved by limits and so on. ) It makes me feel even more confused since we may need to add restrictions to avoid dealing with $\infty-\infty$. Do you have any reference proving those? I find so many textbooks and almost all of them are dealing with real sequences.

In your particular example, you are going to have to worry about $\infty \times 0$

If I define $0*\infty=0*-\infty=0$, do I still need to worry?

Yes: with $a_n=2n\to +\infty$ and $b_n=\frac1n\to 0$, you have $\lim b_na_n=2$
